# Python - Running a function but the number isnt decreased when told to

Tags: python

I have a function which defines a number, than determines what the last digit is, and than does a formula based on the last number, UNTIL the number reaches '1'

YES this is project Euler [Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14)

after the function runs, the original number is to be decreased by 1
and then the function is to be run again.

i already realise how painfully bad this method is but once i know exactly how to get the correct answer, i will make the code alot sexier and quicker to find the answer.

my code:

```
def get_count():
    number = 1000000
    value = number
    count = 0
    while value != 1:
        if value % 10 == 0:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 2:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 4:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 6:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 8:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 1:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 3:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 5:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 7:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 9:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
    print(">>", count, "<<")
    number -= 1
get_count()
get_count()
```

But when i run this it gives me the same answer twice, instead of minusing 1 it stays the same.
am i missing something here?
I am working back from 1Million as i figured the higher "stepcount" would be a higher number, but i will eventually be proven correct or wrong.
James
EDIT:
I have solved my issue, the code for it is:

```
number = 1000000
def get_count():
    value = number
    count = 0
    while value != 1:
        if value % 10 == 0:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 2:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 4:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 6:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 8:
            count += 1
            value *= 0.5
        elif value % 10 == 1:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 3:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 5:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 7:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
        elif value % 10 == 9:
            value = 3*value + 1
            count += 1
    print(">>", number, ":", count, "<<")
num = 1000000
while num > 1:
    num -= 1
    get_count()
    number -= 1
```

Although this is seriously, seriously bad, and super slow to run, it does what i neeeded it to, now i shall be off, to find a way to make it faster, and find a way to give me the direct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables don't exist outside of their enclosing function. Every time you call this function you're getting a whole new variable `number`, `value` and `count` and your assignments are all run again.

If you want variables that outlive your function two options are to make them globals or to make the function a method of a class, and have the variables be instance variables of that class.

Globals approach:

```
number = 1000000
value = number
count = 0

def get_count():
    global number, value, count
    while value != 1:
        if value % 10 == 0:
    # etc.
```

Class approach:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 1000000
        self.value = number
        self.count = 0

    def get_count():
        while self.value != 1:
            if self.value % 10 == 0:
        # etc.
```

Note that in the class approach you need to use `self.` to access the instance variables.

Comment: Or make the function a callable object (i.e. define `__call__()`) itself.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. so i would have to make the "number" variable outside this function, then adjust it accordingly outside the function

Comment: THANKYOU HEAPS!!! :D i think ill go with the global option, as i really dont like class's (how unpythonic of me.. tut tut)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Right. That's just a sugary form of the class approach. :-)